# Android Contact get Photo Thumbnail in one query

Tags: android, mysql, uri, photo, contacts

I had many query and it was taking lot of time to fetch contact data.
So need to convert all query in into one.

I got all other info like display name, mobile number, label, email in one query
but finding prob only with getting pics

Help me to Convert below photo query into single query and get uri of pics :

```
ContentResolver KntRslverVar = getContentResolver();
Cursor ContctKsrVar = KntRslverVar.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},
        null, null, null);

while (ContctKsrVar.moveToNext())
{
    String ContctUidVar = ContctKsrVar.getString(ContctKsrVar.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String ContctNamVar = ContctKsrVar.getString(ContctKsrVar.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String ContctMobVar = ContctKsrVar.getString(ContctKsrVar.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

    Cursor ContctPflPicKsrVar = KntRslverVar.query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?",
            new String[]{ContctUidVar, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},
            null);

    if (ContctPflPicKsrVar != null && ContctPflPicKsrVar.getCount() > 0)
    {
        while(ContctPflPicKsrVar.moveToNext())
        {
            Uri ContctPflPicUriVar = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(ContctUidVar));
            PflPicUriVar = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContctPflPicUriVar, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        }
        ContctPflPicKsrVar.close();
    }
}
```

Try 1 :

```
 Cursor ContctKsrVar = KntRslverVar.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},
        null, null, null);
```

Try 2 :

```
Cursor ContctKsrVar = KntRslverVar.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI},
        null, null, null);
```

Also need help on getting uri from fetched query :

```
Uri KctPflPicUriVar = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(KctUidVar));
PflPicUriVar = Uri.withAppendedPath(KctPflPicUriVar, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

|*| Optimised : Get Display Name and Number with label and Photo Thumbnail in one query : Gets result query in less than 4 sec.

```
ContentResolver contntRslverVar = getContentResolver();
Cursor contctKsrVar = contntRslverVar.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI},
        null, null, null);

while (contctKsrVar.moveToNext())
{
    String contctUidVar = contctKsrVar.getString(contctKsrVar.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String contctNamVar = contctKsrVar.getString(contctKsrVar.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String contctMobVar = contctKsrVar.getString(contctKsrVar.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

    int MobLblTypVar = contctKsrVar.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
    int MobLblTipVar = contctKsrVar.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL);
    MobLblTypVar = contctKsrVar.getInt(MobLblTypVar);

    String contctMobLblVar;
    if(MobLblTypVar == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM)
    {
        contctMobLblVar = contctKsrVar.getString(MobLblTipVar);
    }
    else
    {
        CharSequence MobLblSrgVar = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(getResources(), MobLblTypVar, "Mobile");
        contctMobLblVar = MobLblSrgVar.toString();
    }

    String PflPicSrgVar = contctKsrVar.getString(contctKsrVar.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));
    if(PflPicSrgVar != null) Uri PflPicUriVar = Uri.parse(PflPicSrgVar);
}
```